# JPATH specifies "localhost/var/www"

Tags: apache, url, joomla, lamp

...and any time I try something as simple as `SITE_NAME . '/includes/js/...'` I wind up with `http://localhost/SITE_NAME/SITE_NAME/includes/js/..`

Is there anyway to configure this via Joomla? I've tried everything, but it appears that, for some reason, the pathways system on my machine is broken. I'm not sure if it's Joomla, or if it's just my configuration. If it's not Joomla, would anyone know how to configure this?

**Update**

Not only that, but a relative path specified via my machine refuses to yield its way into the document root path of  my website. For example, I can't do `"../../path/to/file"` without directing that pathway to lead to `SITE_NAME/path/to/file`. Instead it will just reference `http://localhost/path/to/file`. And of course, I receive a 404.

**Update**

Also, when I try to do an `http://` request to a server, I get the same result, except the outcome now is `http://localhost/somesite.com`;

**Update**

I'll post a full blown example of what I'm getting:

(from console debugger in Chrome):

```
GET http://localhost/patention/%3C%22http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js;%22 404 (Not Found)'
```

I'll also post the `.htaccess` I have (of which I know nothing about).

```
##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

#
#  mod_rewrite in use

RewriteEngine On

########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
## Deny access to extension xml files (uncomment out to activate)
#<Files ~ "\.xml$">
#Order allow,deny
#Deny from all
#Satisfy all
#</Files>
## End of deny access to extension xml files
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
#
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits

#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

# RewriteBase /


########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to include a file ( from php ) or want to add some kind of link to the output?
If you want to include a file, you should do something like this:

```
INCLUDE JPATH_ROOT . DS . 'my' . DS . 'folder' . DS . 'myfile.php';
```

But if what you want is, for example, to add a script to your file, you should do it in one of these ways (both of them should work):

```
<a href="<?php echo JUri::root() . 'includes/js/myfile.js'"> ....
```

or

```
<a href="/includes/js/myfile.js">...
```

The second option should work fine as long as /includes is in your joomla root.
If it is still not working, could you post an example of code where you try to use that "include"?

I hope it helped!